# Retrieve dictionary from dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this :

```
{
  "A" : {
    "A1" : {
      "er" : false,
      "hy" : false,
      "fv" : false,
      "fr" : false
    },
    "A2" : {
      "fr" : false,
      "ty" : false,
      "ty" : false,
    },
  "B" : {
    "B1" : {
      "er" : false,
      "hy" : false,
      "fv" : false,
      "fr" : false
    },
    "B2" : {
      "fr" : false,
      "ty" : false,
      "ty" : false,
    },
  }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve values of A and B dictionary as a separate dictionaries

I have tried

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict =
    jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

Dictionary<string, object> dict1 = dict["A"];//error over here
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to  'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

how to resolve this?

Comment: Why not `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>` ?

Comment: Listen to the compiler! **`(are you missing a cast?)`**. Better yet, specify the actual types as generic parameters instead of `object`.

Comment: In existing code, `dict["A"]` will have type object. What have you put there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>> dict = 
    jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>>(json);
Dictionary<string, bool> dict1 = dict["A"];
```